# Optimizing Images via PHP

Tags: php, image, optimization

I would like to build a PHP script to optimize images similarly to how PunyPNG or Kraken.io optimizes images. Essentially, I would need to be able to take .jpeg, .png, and .gif images and reduce their file size as much as possible without losing quality (or with minimal quality loss).

These services offer APIs, but I would like to avoid unnecessary costs, and I do not want to be limited by a specific number of daily uses.

Can this be done with something like ImageMagick? Is it even possible, or is it far too complicated?

Comment: png is non-lossy. you cannot "optimize" without fundamentally fiddling with the image's contents, or bumping up the compression level. jpeg optimization generally involves lowering the quality setting, but it's non-trivial to figure out how far you can go that route before you get too many visual artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

talking about re-sizing images, they were never an issue, there are couple of tools that help you do that in bulk. Since you specifically say PHP, I am expecting you would be using it for displaying it on a page. for the very same purpose I wrote this little script not so long ago, which might be of some help to you. Fork it here https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize

Answer (score 1):

Spatie has a decent package that gets updated regularly, I've been using for a while without problems:

https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer